# Coordinate transformation in a double integral using sympy

Tags: sympy, integral, polar-coordinates

How do I do a coordinate transformation (cartesian to polar) in a double integral using sympy? For example, from:

```
Integral(exp(-x**2-y**2), (x,-oo,oo), (y,-oo,oo))
```

To:

```
Integral(exp(-r**2)*r, (r,0,oo), (t,0,2*pi))
```

Comment: I don't think SymPy has a built in function for doing this yet, but that doesn't preclude the possibility of doing it manually.

Comment: Technically, it wouldn't be that hard to implement the transformation of the integrand expression, it's a variable substitution multiplied by the jacobian determinant of the transformation. The hard part is the determination of the integration limits for the new variables.